# How to easily copy only matching field value from one object to another without modifying the unmatched field in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I Have two classes:

```
Car 
{
  string Color;
}

ModifiedCar{
  string Color;
  int Price;
}
```

I created two object:

```
var obj1 = new Car{
 Color = "red";
}

var obj2 = new ModifiedCar{
  Color = "green";
  Price = 330442;
}
```

Now I want to copy matching fields value(which is color field) from obj1 to obj2 without modifying price.
Resulting object that I want:

```
obj2 ={
   Color = "red";
   Price = 330442;
}
```

I can do it by `obj2.color = obj1.color`  , but When the field is more, it will be problematic. I want to know, is there any built-in function or technique by which I can easily achieve this without manually copying each field?

Comment: Please don't accept ChatGPT-generated answers. For one thing, they're wrong and very, VERY slow. On each calls you end up making expensive Reflection calls that retrieve the exact same information. You pay the cost every time for no reason at all. Libraries like AutoMapper solve this by caching Reflection information.

Comment: Automapper will also take care of case differences, something the bad answer doesn't do

Comment: For a single mapping, Is is good to load a library into a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you are trying to do is called object to object mapping. There are a set of available libraries in c# to help you do that, most notably Automapper.

You can also use reflection to find the fields you want and map their values across objects, although this approach's performance would not be great.